# Using redis with heroku

Tags: heroku, redis

This is my first time using redis and the only reason I am is because I'm trying out [autocomplete search tutorial](http://josephndungu.com/tutorials/fast-autocomplete-search-terms-rails). The tutorial works perfectly in development but I'm having trouble setting up redis for heroku.

I already followed [these steps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rediscloud#using-redis-from-ruby) on the heroku docs for setting up redis but when I run `heroku run rake db:seed` I get `Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)`

I'm not very familiar with heroku so if you guys need any more information let me know.

**Edit**

I've completed the initializer steps shown [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rediscloud#getting-started) and when I run `heroku config:get REDISCLOUD_URL` the result is exactly the same as the Redis Cloud URL under the config vars section of my Heroku settings.

Following the documentation, I then set up config/initializers/redis.rb like so:

```
if ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"]
    $redis = Redis.new(:url => ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"])
end
```

Just to check, I tried substituting the actual URL for redis cloud inside the if block instead of just the `REDISCLOUD_URL` variable but that didn't work. My error message hasn't changed when I try to seed the heroku db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not enough to just create a `$redis` variable that points to the installed Redis server, you also need to tell Soulmate about it, otherwise it will default to localhost.

From the [Soulmate README](https://github.com/seatgeek/soulmate#mounting-soulmate-into-a-rails-app) you should be able to do something like this in an initializer (instead of your current `redis.rb` initializer, which you won’t need unless you are using Redis somewhere else in your app):

```
if ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"]
  Soulmate.redis = ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"]
end
```

Looking at the [Soulmate source](https://github.com/seatgeek/soulmate/blob/v1.1.0/lib/soulmate/config.rb#L33), an easier way may be to set the `REDIS_URL` environment variable to the Redis url, either instead of or as well as `REDISCLOUD_URL`, as it looks like Soulmate checks this before falling back to localhost.

Comment: I used a soulmate initializer like you suggested instead of the redis one and it seems to have worked a charm. I've successfully seeded my heroku db at any rate. Thanks so much for this, it was wrecking my head! I'll award the bounty as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: @SoSimple It's great that you've found the solution! This suggests that your the Redis gem that your app is using doesn't support creating a connection using that syntax - what are you using?

Comment: @ItamarHaber As matt said the issue was that I forgot about soulmate  and needed to tell it to look to the cloud instead of localhost. I just replaced config/initializers/redis.rb with soulmate.rb and everything seems to be working fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to connect to a local Redis instance, instead the one from Redis Cloud - make sure you've completed the initializer step as detailed in order to resolve this.

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner, I was having some issues with my PC. I've done those steps to setup redis cloud but it's still trying to connect to a local version. Any ideas?

Comment: Please add the relevant intializer code to your question :)